# C# large Linq query freezing Winform UI

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I am creating an application that compare two databases together one being an oracle database the other being a MySQL database. After it compares the two databases it will then move any data over that the MySQL database is missing into the MySQL database. It then updates to a visual monitor to tell the end user that data has been moved over.

I have no trouble getting the compare done and moving the new lines over but I believe the LINQ query I am using is causing the winform UI to freeze up for almost a minute and a half. The databases contain anywhere between 18,000 - 25,000 lines each.

The query looks like this:

```
var matched = from table1 in oClone.AsEnumerable()
                              join table2 in mClone.AsEnumerable() on table1.Field<decimal>("CASEID") equals table2.Field<Int64>("CASEID")
                              where table1.Field<decimal>("CASEID") == table2.Field<Int64>("CASEID") || 
                              table1.Field<string>("CASENAME") == table2.Field<string>("CASENAME") || 
                              table1.Field<DateTime>("CREATEDDATE") == table2.Field<DateTime>("CREATEDDATE") || 
                              table1.Field<int>("STUDYMODEID") == table2.Field<int>("STUDYMODEID") || 
                              table1.Field<string>("ENVIRONMENT") == table2.Field<string>("ENVIRONMENT")
                              select table1;
                var missing = from table1 in oClone.AsEnumerable()
                              where !matched.Contains(table1)
                              select table1;

                missingLines = missing.CopyToDataTable();
                AddNewLines(missingLines);
```

Is there any way that I could optimize the query to stop the freezing of the UI?

Comment: Well for starters don't pull the entirety of all of those tables into memory and then join them,  do the work on the DB end.  Then do the query asynchronously, rather than synchronously.

Comment: @SWard You're joining them on the primary key *after pulling the entirety of both tables into memory*, not *before* materializing the results of the query into memory.

Comment: @Servy so I should not be using .AsEnumerable

Comment: @SWard Are you sure the slow part is the posted in memory query, and not the initial `DataTable` population and/or `AddNewLines` method?

Comment: @IvanStoev yeah I checked both of those first by just dumping a lot of data into both and they don't bog down.

Comment: I think the problem is that your `matched` query is reevaluated every time inside `!matched.Contains(table1)` filter of the `missing` query. Which leads to O(N^2) time complexity. Do you need the `matched` for something else?

Comment: @IvanStoev `matched` is only used in the query nowhere else in the application is it called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109729/discussion-between-ivan-stoev-and-sward).

Comment: Why do you use data tables and not classes? All these `Field` calls take far more time than simply accessing object properties.

Comment: @GertArnold Would having a class be better? I feel like turning ever line into an object would still cause the memory problem.

Comment: I was just wondering. Building data tables also takes time. You could materialize the database data into classes instead by using an ORM like Entity Framework or a micro-ORM like Dapper (the fastest option) and then do the comparison by LINQ that is far less clunky to write - and probably faster.